# Win8 to WP App async/await conversation

Tags: c#, wcf, asynchronous, windows-phone-8, windows-8

In the process of converting a Windows 8 app to Windows Phone but encountering a problem with the WCF connections and asynchronous communication. To summarise, I am trying to call a WCF service which connects to a Ms SQL Server but receive “cannot await void” for all the “await serviceClient.getEmployeesAsync();” or similar.

What is the simplest way to solve this problem as I have quite a few methods similar to this which work fine in the Windows 8 app but not Windows Phone app.

```
private async void btnGetAllStaff_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Create a client object to access the service
        DataProvider.DataProviderClient serviceClient = new DataProvider.DataProviderClient();

        //Get the staff objects from the service
        ObservableCollection<DataProvider.Employee> employees = await serviceClient.getEmployeesAsync();

        //Add the objects to the list view
        foreach (DataProvider.Employee employee in employees)
        {
            lstStaff.Items.Add(employee.FirstName+" "+employee.LastName);
        }
    }
```

I should add that I am new to WCF and network programming in general!!

Thanks

Comment: You can only await a Task, or Task<T>. The getEmployeesAsync method needs to return a Task or Task<T>

Comment: @ShawnKendrot That's not strictly true.  You can await anything that has a `GetAwaiter` method that returns an object with a given set of methods.  `Task` has such a method.  You can create your own types that can be awaitable though too.

Comment: Your error message states getEmployeesAsync is returning void, you cannot await a void

Comment: Thanks but how do I solve this?

Comment: @TheIdiot You need to get an awaitable object if you want to await something.  Without knowing the API of the asynchronous class you're using, we can't really say how to go about getting something you can `await`.  There are many ways of having an asynchronous method.

Comment: do you own the service and are able to make changes to `getEmployeesAsync()`?

Comment: Yes I have full control of the WCF Service.

Answer (score 0):

The WCF proxy generator built-in to Visual Studio will generate [TAP methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873175.aspx), but only if it knows the client platform supports `async` natively. Otherwise, it will create [APM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228963%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [EAP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228969%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) endpoints. What you're seeing is that your client proxy method ending in `Async` is TAP on the Windows Store platform, but EAP on the Windows Phone platform.

Your best bet is to try to reuse the WCF client proxy code in your projects; e.g., put it in a Portable Class Library and use the generated TAP methods. If you can't get that to work, then put the client proxy in the PCL and create [TAP wrappers for the APM endpoints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873178%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#ApmToTap).

Comment: Thanks. I can also make changes to the WCF service or create a new service for WP if that's a better option?

Comment: @TheIdiot: No. The problem is in the WCF client proxy creation.